# Which is the location of "file" command?

Tags: binary

When we check the file type, we use `file` command to do it. I guess that `file` command is a binary. So, I look in bin folder for it, which I didn't find. The question is if it's a binary, where is that binary located?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `which` command to locate a command:

```
which file
```

See `man which` for more info.

Comment: As a general rule, `type` is better since it can also find shell functions and aliases. For (many) more details, see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/22222).

Comment: @terdon IMO this is primarily opinion-based and may depends about the shell where we use them, on how do we want to use the output, or the exit status, a.o. If we look at `man which` and at `help type`, we can see that `which` command will win in this case where the OP was interested about a specific command, not shell functions, aliases, builtins, keywords a.o.

Answer (score 1):

In most shells, including bash, you can use the `type` command to find the location of a command:

```
$ type file
file is /usr/bin/file
```

Answer (score 0):

It's located in /usr/bin/file.

The command below will locate things for you. You can replace file with whatever.

```
which file
```

Checking for specific stuff in /usr/bin will show you it's there...

```
cd /usr/bin; ls -l | grep "file"
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use the `type` shell builtin as @FlorianDiesch [suggested](https://askubuntu.com/a/447348/85695). The `which` command can also do it but, among [various other problems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/22222), it does not deal gracefully with aliases or shell functions.

The shell builtin `type` (which is available on `bash`,`sh`,`dash`,`fish`,`zsh`, `ksh` and probably others), does not have these problems:

```
$ type file
file is /usr/bin/file

$ type ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=tty'

$ type fix_config
fix_config is a function
fix_config () 
{ 
    old="ha";
    new="ba";
    sed -i.bak "17 s/$old/$new/" .config;
    cat .config;
    cp .config.bak .config
}
```

Compare the above to

```
$ which file
/usr/bin/file

$ which ls
/bin/ls

$ which fix_config
$
```